# How to find and replace the column name?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find and replace the column name.

I want to loop in the first row only but my code loops the entire sheet.

[image: Excel file]

```vb
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim data As Variant

Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ERT")

fndList = Array("colon.", _
                "Selec:", _
                "Sele, _
                "Submi")
                
rplcList = Array("A", "A1", "S1", "D1")

With sht

    'Loop through each item in Array lists
    For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
        'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
        'For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Exp")
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        'Next sht
    Next x
  
End With
```

I want to only find and replace the array value from first Row A1 till end of 1 row.

Comment: VBA help says regarding `WorkSheet.Cells` property: *Returns a Range object that represents all the cells on the worksheet (not just the cells that are currently in use.* And you are calling `sht.Cells.Replace ...` where `sht` is a worksheet. Change `sht` to refer to a `Range` instead.

Comment: Ok, so keep sht but declare a range object that you use to replace those column names, e.g. `Dim rng As Range` and `rng = sht.Range("A1:F1")`. Then call `rng.Replace ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way. It will try matching the first array elements on the first row headers and replace the found one with the corresponding string from the second:

```
Sub ReplaceHeaders()
  Dim shT As Worksheet, lastCol As Long, fndList, rplcList, rngHd As Range, mtch, i As Long
  
  Set shT = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Final Exclusion")
  lastCol = shT.cells(1, shT.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  
  fndList = Array("Enter one or more MSOs or ESOs to be excluded.  Separate multiple values using a semicolon.", _
                "Select the datasets from which you wish to exclude these MSOs:", _
                "Select the reason code for the exclusion:", _
                "Submitter's CWSID")

 rplcList = Array("MSO", "SOCS", "Reason's", "Submitter")
 Set rngHd = shT.Range(shT.cells(1, 1), shT.cells(1, lastCol))
 For i = 0 To UBound(fndList)
    mtch = Application.match(fndList(i), rngHd, 0)
    If Not IsError(mtch) Then
        rngHd(1, mtch).Value = rplcList(i)
    End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: super its perfect now

Answer (score 0):

```
dict= 'old_name':'new_name'

new_df=df.rename(columns={'MSO':'mso',
'SOCS':'socs','KPI':'kpi','Reason's':'reason',
'submitter':'submitter'}
```